# Как использовать Qthread в графической и неграфической версии?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Я пишу приложение "Нечеткий поиск", в котором на вход подается текст, в котором могут быть опечатки и набор слова, которые нужно в нем найти. На выходе информация о том, какие слова входят (даже если они с опечатками).

Я написала класс гуи, но во время долгих вычислений он замораживался. Тогда я написала класс, наследующийся от QThread и в него поместила эти вычисления, а также из него эмитила сигналы, которые ловились в гуи классе для того, чтобы двигать прогресс бар.

Все бы ничего, но мне еще надо написать вторую версию без гуишной формы, просто в консоли дать два аргменты - файл с текстом и файл со словами и на выходе напечатать список вхождений. Для этого мне нужны методы из класса, наследованного от QThread, но без QEventLoop QThread не работает, а в консольной версии странно было бы пользоваться графической библиотекой.

Преподаватель посоветовал использовать Thread из модуля threading, но я никак не могу найти, как там посылать сигналы, нужные для графики, как это сделано в PyQt. Возможно существует еще какое-то решение этой проблемы.

Это класс, наследующийся от QThread:

```
import text_methods
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread


class FuzzySearch(QThread):
    sig_words_count = pyqtSignal(int)
    sig_step = pyqtSignal(int)
    sig_done = pyqtSignal(bool)
    sig_insertions = pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_insertions_indexes = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, text, words, case_sensitive):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text
        self.words = words
        self.case_sensitive = case_sensitive
        self.insertions_indexes = {}
        self.text_dict = {}

    def run(self):
        self.get_insertions_info(self.text, self.words)

    def find_insertions_of_word(self, word, word_number):
        word_insertions = {}
        for textword in self.text_dict.keys():
            if text_methods.is_optimal_distance(word, textword):
                word_insertions[textword] = self.text_dict[textword]
                for index in self.text_dict[textword]:
                    self.insertions_indexes[index] = index + len(textword)
        self.sig_step.emit(word_number)
        return word_insertions

    '''Get information about insertions of words in the text'''
    def find_insertions(self, text, words):
        word_number = 1
        insertions = {}
        self.text_dict = text_methods.transform_text_to_dict(text, self.case_sensitive)
        words_list = text_methods.transform_words_to_list(words, self.case_sensitive)
        self.sig_words_count.emit(len(words_list))
        for word in words_list:
            print(word_number)
            insertions[word] = self.find_insertions_of_word(word, word_number)
            word_number += 1
        self.insertions_indexes = sorted(self.insertions_indexes.items())
        return insertions

    '''Get information about insertions of words in the text in special format'''
    def get_insertions_info(self, text, words):
        insertions = self.find_insertions(text, words)
        insertions_info = ''
        for word in insertions.keys():
            insertions_info += 'Вы искали слово "' + word + '"\n'
            if len(insertions[word]) == 0:
                insertions_info += '  По этому запросу не было найдено слов\n'
            else:
                insertions_info += '  По этому запросу были найдены слова:\n'
                for textword in insertions[word].keys():
                    insertions_info += '   "' + textword + '" на позициях: '
                    insertions_info += ", ".join([str(i) for i in insertions[word][textword]])
                    insertions_info += '\n'
        self.sig_done.emit(True)
        self.sig_insertions.emit(insertions_info)
        self.sig_insertions_indexes.emit(self.insertions_indexes)
        self.quit()
```

Здесь много сигналов, которые соединение со слотами в графическом модуле классе FindButton методе find_insertions
As you see there are a lot of emitted signals that I transfer to gui module where they connect to slots in class FindButton in method find_insertions:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget,\
                            QLabel, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog,\
                            QMessageBox, QProgressBar, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from fuzzysearch import FuzzySearch
import sys


class OpenButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name, font, textedit):
        super().__init__(name, font=font)
        self.textedit = textedit
        self.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

    def open_dialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        if fname[0]:
            with open(fname[0], 'r') as f:
                data = f.read()
                self.textedit.setText(data)


class FindButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name, font, text, words, result, window):
        super().__init__(name, font=font)
        self.window = window
        self.textedit = text
        self.wordsedit = words
        self.resultedit = result
        self.checkbox = window.case_sensitive_checkbox
        self.clicked.connect(self.find_insertions)

    def find_insertions(self):
        text = self.textedit.toPlainText()
        words = self.wordsedit.toPlainText()
        if text == '':
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Нет текста',
                                    'Текст не был введен. \nВведите текст.')
        elif words == '':
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Нет слов',
                                    'Слова не были введены. \nВведите слова через запятую.')
        else:
            self.setDisabled(True)
            self.text_editor = TextEditor(text, self.textedit)
            self.fuzzy_search = FuzzySearch(text, words, self.checkbox.checkState())
            self.fuzzy_search.sig_words_count.connect(self.window.progress_bar.setMaximum)
            self.fuzzy_search.sig_step.connect(self.window.progress_bar.setValue)
            self.fuzzy_search.sig_done.connect(self.setEnabled)
            self.fuzzy_search.sig_insertions.connect(self.resultedit.setText)
            self.fuzzy_search.sig_insertions_indexes.connect(self.text_editor.mark)
            self.fuzzy_search.start()


class TextEditor:
    def __init__(self, text, textedit):
        self.text = text
        self.textedit = textedit

    def mark(self, to_mark):
        self.textedit.clear()
        current_index = 0
        for item in to_mark:
            self.write_not_marked_text(self.text[current_index:item[0]])
            self.write_marked_text(self.text[item[0]:item[1]])
            current_index = item[1]
        self.write_not_marked_text(self.text[current_index:])

    def write_not_marked_text(self, text):
        font = QFont("Times", 10)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.textedit.setCurrentFont(font)
        self.textedit.setTextColor(Qt.black)
        self.textedit.insertPlainText(text)

    def write_marked_text(self, text):
        font = QFont("Times", 10)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.textedit.setCurrentFont(font)
        self.textedit.setTextColor(Qt.red)
        self.textedit.insertPlainText(text)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, font):
        super().__init__()
        self.standard_font = font
        self.text_edit_font = QFont("Times", 10)

        text_label = QLabel("Введите или откройте текст",
                            font=self.standard_font)
        words_label = QLabel("Введите или откройте слова (через запятую)",
                             font=self.standard_font)
        result_label = QLabel("Результат",
                              font=self.standard_font)

        text_edit = QTextEdit(font=self.text_edit_font)
        words_edit = QTextEdit(font=self.text_edit_font)
        result_edit = QTextEdit(font=self.text_edit_font)

        self.case_sensitive_checkbox = QCheckBox('Учитывать регистр')
        self.case_sensitive_checkbox.setFont(self.standard_font)

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)

        open_btn1 = OpenButton("Открыть", self.standard_font, text_edit)
        open_btn2 = OpenButton("Открыть", self.standard_font, words_edit)
        find_btn = FindButton("Найти слова в тексте", self.standard_font,
                              text_edit, words_edit, result_edit, self)


        text_label_box = QHBoxLayout()
        text_label_box.addWidget(text_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        text_label_box.addWidget(open_btn1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)

        words_label_box = QHBoxLayout()
        words_label_box.addWidget(words_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        words_label_box.addWidget(open_btn2, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)

        words_box = QVBoxLayout()
        words_box.addLayout(words_label_box)
        words_box.addWidget(words_edit)

        result_box = QVBoxLayout()
        result_box.addWidget(result_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        result_box.addWidget(result_edit)

        bottom_box = QHBoxLayout()
        bottom_box.addLayout(words_box)
        bottom_box.addLayout(result_box)

        find_and_progress_box = QHBoxLayout()
        find_and_progress_box.addWidget(find_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        find_and_progress_box.addWidget(self.case_sensitive_checkbox)
        find_and_progress_box.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

        main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        main_box.addLayout(text_label_box)
        main_box.addWidget(text_edit)
        main_box.addLayout(bottom_box)
        main_box.addLayout(find_and_progress_box)

        self.setLayout(main_box)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1100, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Нечеткий поиск')
        self.show()


def start_application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window(QFont("Times", 12))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И графика замечательно работает, но вот консольная версия не работает без QEventLoop

```
import fuzzysearch


class ConsoleVersion():
    def __init__(self, text, words):
        self.text = text
        self.words = words

    def search_words_in_text(self):
        with self.text:
            with self.words:
                self.f = fuzzysearch.FuzzySearch(self.text.read(), self.words.read(), False)
                self.f.sig_insertions.connect(self.get_insertions)
                self.f.start()


    def get_insertions(self, insertions):
        print(insertions)
```

и в главном файле я парсю аргументы и на их основе выбираю версию

```
import argparse
import gui
import console_version

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fuzzy search in text')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--graphics', help='graphical version', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--console', help='console version', nargs=2, type=argparse.FileType('r'), metavar=('TEXTFILE', 'WORDSFILE'))
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    if args.graphics:
        gui.start_application()
    if args.console:
        cv = console_version.ConsoleVersion(args.console[0], args.console[1])
        cv.search_words_in_text()
```

что же делать в таком случае?

Comment: Используйте `QCoreApplication` для консольной версии.